# OpenCV drawContours isn't saving

Tags: python, opencv

I've got an RGBA image, which I want to draw the contour for, and save with the contour drawn.
I have the following code:

```
skin = cv.imread("-path-", cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

_, mask = cv.threshold(skin[:, :, 3], 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(mask, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

largest_contour = max(contours, key=cv.contourArea)

skin = cv.drawContours(skin, [largest_contour], 0, (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

if I use

```
cv.imshow("-title-", skin)
```

I can see the contours, but if I do:

```
cv.imwrite("-path-", skin)
```

The original image is saved.

How do I save the image with the contours drawn in?

*It has something to do with the transparency of the original image, where the contours are*

Answer (score 1):

In OpenCV, you have cv2.imwrite() function.

Store the image on which contours to a variable.

let's say

```
new_skin = drawContours(skin,[largest_contour], 0, (0, 255, 0), 3) # store in new variable
cv2.imwrite("newskin.png",new_skin) # save to file
```

Try this to save image locally.

Answer (score 0):

It was the transparency of the contours, I don't know why but it shined on me after posting.

the solution was to add the following line:

```
skin[:, :, 3] = cv.drawContours(skin[:, :, 3].astype(np.uint8), [largest_contour], 0, (255), 3)
```